# How to set data format in emails generated with Spring's MimeMessageHelper

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

Spring's `org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.setSentDate(Date date)` takes a date that will be set in the header of the email, but not a format. I need to specify a particular format.

I checked the source and `MimeMessage` uses `javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat` to format it, but it doesn't have a way to *set* the format from the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternately set a custom header using the MimeMessage.addHeader(String, String) method, and insert the formatted date using SimpleDateFormat.format(Date):

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // you specify the format for your date
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).format(new Date());
MimeMessage mimeMessage = //get message from wherever
mimeMessage.addHeader("Date", formattedDate);
```

Comment: Funny thing, looking through the MimeMessage code, when using the MimeMessageHelper.setSentDate(), it delegates to MimeMessage.setSentDate() which does the same thing I described in this answer, as the MailDateFormat is an extenstion to SimpleDateFormat, and it formats the Date you pass to the method. The only thing is I can't see any other way to modify the format. But essentially its the same solution.

Comment: The format of the Date header is defined in the internet standard, why would you want to format the date header in a non-standard way?

Comment: Custom use cases perhaps

Comment: What customer?  What use case?  Tell them they're wrong, or confused, or misguided.